# row and col classes are not expending the entire available width unless using form or p elements

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5, angular-bootstrap

I keep getting strange behaviors when using bootstrap in the application I'm working on. This is the first time I encounter such behavior.

Here's the HTML

```
<div class="row" style="background-color: blue; padding: 2rem; width: 100%;">
  <div class="col-6" style="background-color: yellow;">
    <label for="useProdAddress">
     <input type="checkbox"id="useProdAddress">
     Use Producer Address
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6" style="background-color: orange;">
   <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary">
    Add Address
   </button>
  </div>
 </div>
```

[image]

As shown in the above screenshot, the entire contain occupies like the 1/3 of the page. adding width = 100% didn't make any different.

However, those are working

- using **px** or **rem** for width makes the div.row wider.
- using **p** or **form** elements

  ```
   <div class="col-6" style="background-color: orange;">
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
   </div>
  ```

[image]

I don't know whether the reason is that I'm using the **nav angular-bootstrap** component.

```
<div class="d-flex">
<ul ngbNav #nav="ngbNav" [(activeId)]="active" class="nav-pills" orientation="vertical">
    ...
    <li ngbNavItem="locations">
        <a ngbNavLink>Locations</a>
        <ng-template ngbNavContent>
            <app-locations></app-locations>
        </ng-template>
    </li>
    ...
</ul>

<div [ngbNavOutlet]="nav" class="ms-4"></div>
```

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the width style first. `<div class="row" style="width: 100%; background-color: blue; padding: 2rem;">`